# Jquery: need to set width of div inside table

Tags: jquery

Right now im trying to grab the ul and put it under the expanded tr when clicked (to make it seem expanded). It moves the ul but it stays the width of the first th in the thead. I need the ul to be able to move the entire width of the table.

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="header">number</th>
        <th class="header">details</th>
        <th class="header">first name</th>
        <th class="header">last name</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody> 
        <tr>
        <td>12345</td>
        <td class="expandable">Description
            <ul>
                <li><b>Sed ut:</b> perspiciatis unde omnis  error sit voluptatem</li>
                <li><b>Sed ut:</b> perspiciatis unde omnis  error sit voluptatem</li>
                <li><b>Sed ut:</b> perspiciatis unde omnis  error sit voluptatem</li>
            </ul>
        </td>
        <td>john</td>
        <td>smith</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

here the js

```
function legDesc(el){
el.click(function(){

var bag = $(this)
var width = bag.width()
var desc = bag.find('ul')
var parent = bag.parent()
bag.prev().css('width', width)

if($('.leg-desc ul').length > 0){
        desc.insertAfter(parent)
}else{
        var ul = el.parent().next()
        parent.next().prev().find('.leg-desc').append(ul)
}
bag.parents('tr').toggleClass('expanded')
})
}
  legDesc($('.leg-desc'))
```

Comment: How about creating a new row in the table just below the current one, with a <td colspan="4"> and putting the ul there?

Comment: Also, where is the item with class leg-desk that the user will be clicking on?  I don't see it in your html.

Comment: That actually works well, but now the issue I will have is that i have zebra stripes will apply to it and it will look like another row opposed to an expanded of the clicked row. Any ideas on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the whole thing to be one table, you'll need to use colspan to let your ul cross multiple cells, like in this fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/s8JZg/1/

If you want to give the appearance of a row expanding but the header remaining the same, you'll need to make them two separate tables, because, as crush pointed out, columns within the same table must maintain the same width.  You can use css rules to maintain the same column widths in the two tables.

Answer (score 0):

you could set `white-space: nowrap` in css on the li elements

Comment: Thats the problem. Currently it stays the width of the th but if I add width to it, it pushed the th which is bad. I just need it to expand without touching the thead

Comment: I'm confused. The TH and TD in the same column HAVE to be the same width. What am I missing?